# AMChart Displaying multiple charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Can anybody help me, why the second dataset and graph are not displaying,

I have added

```
      chart.dataSets = [dataSet1,dataSet2];

      chart.panels = [stockPanel1,stockPanel2];
```

jsfiddle is here

```
http://jsfiddle.net/6q9c578q/
```

-George

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the [dataSetSelector](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSetSelector) it will help you to understand how it works in general.

```
chart.dataSetSelector = {};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6q9c578q/2/

Each dataset contains the data for all panels, if you select another dataset (to compare) you can use the [fieldMappings](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSet#fieldMappings) to map those fields to those field names you gave to your graphs on the panels.

In your case if you enable the second dataset which has different datafields as the main one it has nothing to compare and shows nothing, same for the other side if you select the second dataset ( as main dataset ) and select the first to compare it won't show any data on the first panel.